# async GET image in CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, afnetworking-2, sdwebimage

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=harry&country=us&entity=movie . I need to get an image from this url and show in collection view. I used 'AFNetworking' and "SDWebImage" libraries. I am stuck in programming. how to use this key "artworkUrl100" which is in that url and what should be written in cellforitematindexpath ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, SDWebImage takes care of loading the image in the background without the need for AFNetworking. Create a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` that contains a `UIImageView` inside.

Inside `cellforitematindexpath`, you can create a new instance of the custom cell, and invoke SDWebImage load image method onto that cell. The image should then be automatically loaded in the background. Return the modified cell.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I created pod for SDImageview and AFNetworking ? Is it ok ?